# Spice : Error Message: Note: No ".plot", ".print", or ".fourier" lines; no simulations run

Tags: spice

I try to run a simple RLC circuit under ngspice in batch mode and the netlist is written as follows:

```
Series RLC Circuit
V1 1 0 ac 100 0 
R1 1 2 200 
L1 2 3 0.125
C1 3 0 1U
.ac LIN 10 10 100
print ac v(1) i(V1)
.END
```

I run this netlist by giving the following command:

```
ngspice -b RLC.cir
```

And i get the following Error Massage which I don't understand :-(!

```
Circuit: series rlc circuit

Doing analysis at TEMP = 27.000000 and TNOM = 27.000000

Warning: v1: has no value, DC 0 assumed

No. of Data Rows : 10
Error(parse.c--checkvalid): data: no such vector.
Note: No ".plot", ".print", or ".fourier" lines; no simulations run
```

Comment: so do you need to add a '.' before your print line?

Answer (score 1):

First error is because your ac is NOT AC, it's not seeing it and defaulting to a current probe.

Print line must be .print AC and Maybe  .PRINT AC

I notice that in your print statement case is different on on v vs. V.