# ngspice not printing currents for any circuit

Tags: current, spice

I'm reading an EE book that references SPICE so to follow along on my linux machine I installed ngspice.  I can't output current for any circuits!  I've tried passing the file with -r option and multiple circuits.  Can never get a current output!

I googled and tried other posts [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/56018/spice-error-message-note-no-plot-print-or-fourier-lines-no-simul) but nothing seems to work.  I'm starting to wonder if this is an install / configuration issue?

Starting with a simple series circuit with the intent to print voltage at each resistor and current at my source I loaded the following netlist:

```
series circuit
v1 1 0
r1 1 2 3k
r2 2 3 10k
r3 3 0 5k
.dc v1 9 9 1
.print dc v(1,2) v(2,3) v(3,0) i(v1)
.end
```

and received errors:
Warning: v1: has no value, DC 0 assumed
Warning: can't parse '0': ignored

My voltage outputs are correct per hand calcs so I know ngspice is calculating the right current.

reducing .print line to just get current::

```
.print i(v1)
```

yields error:

```
Error: .print: no i(v1) analysis found.
```

I've also tried defining my source different as:

```
v1 1 0 dc 9
```

same errors.

I've tried many different circuits and can never get ngspice to output current for my sources (I have created 0 voltage sources near resistances on parallel circuits as well).
The voltage outputs are all correct

I also tried a netlist with no .print line (I thought I've seen others with default output):

```
series circuit
v1 1 0 dc 9
r1 1 2 3k
r2 2 3 10k
r3 3 0 5k
.end
```

with this error:

```
Note: No ".plot", ".print", or ".fourier" lines; no simulations run
```

isn't there a default output without needing a .print line?

More importantly is there a configuration file not setup properly?  thoughts?

any direction is greatly appreciate... Thank you

Comment: Take a look at [LT Spice](http://www.linear.com/designtools/software/) It's Windows software but runs well on Linux machines with Wine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first circuit is correct, you don't have errors, just warnings. You can ignore the warning about v1 or define it with a value like v1 1 0 9. I've just tested your initial circuit with ngspice (linux) and it did give the correct value for the current (-5.00000e-04) through the source v1.

> `.print i(v1)`
>
> yields error:
>
> `Error: .print: no i(v1) analysis found.`

You forgot the analysis type parameter before the output variable: .print dc i(v1).

Note: As mentioned on this answer [How to plot current in ngspice?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/18690/how-to-plot-current-in-ngspice) with ngspice you only can get currents through independent voltage sources. If you have a more complex circuit you would need to add a zero volt source (in series) with the component to get its current.

Answer (score 1):

there are some problems with your .cir file.

`.dc v1 9 9 1`

you forgot a minus sign.

`.dc v1 -9 9 1`

this will cause a warning

`v1 1 0`

be more verbose and write

`v1 1 0 DC=0V`

the node `0` is something special, thus

`.print dc v(3,0)`

should be

`.print dc v(3)`

and ngspice cant process `i(node)` expressions.
replace this with

`.print dc v1#branch`

then be sure to have a copy of the ngspice manual.pdf,
its precious.

and perhaps learn the .control/.endc language, for example
try `ngspice thisfile.cir`
with

```
series circuit

v1 1 0 DC=0
r1 1 2 3k
r2 2 3 10k
r3 3 0 5k

.control
dc v1 -9 9 1
* this will show you which vectors are available
display
* this will plot some of them
plot v(1,2) v(2,3) v(3)
plot v1#branch
plot v(3)^2
.endc

.end
```